I am getting a no such column error only when running tests
Edit:
I deleted by database and this happens when migrating from scratch, so something seems wrong with my basic sequence of migrations.
Basically I have (step 1 actually being step 14 but w/e)

create model

populate the model with a fixture

add a new column to the model


when it gets to step 2 it dies because of the "column does not exist" error.
At that point the database does not have the column, nor does the fixture it is applying make any reference to it.

Perhaps this is leaving out some key detail and exposing my relative newness to django, but I tried to isolate my issue to the fewest steps to reproduce the problem.
Starting state: App running fine, tests all passing.

Add one nullable column to an existing model.
makemigrations
migrate

New state: App runs fine, running tests produces an error.
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Found 23 test(s).
Installed 5 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/f/.virtualenvs/mgmt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/f/.virtualenvs/mgmt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: recommended_for_text

recommend_for_text is the name of the new column.
recommended_for_text = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=256)

It shows up in my view in the app as expected, just running the tests is causing me an issue.
Update:
Before the change running test output:
Found 23 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Installed 5 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Installed 9 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.......................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 23 tests in 2.286s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

and after:
Found 23 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Installed 5 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/f/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/f/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: recommended_for_text

0016_migration.py:
# Generated by Django 4.1.13 on 2024-04-25 17:34

from django.db import migrations, models


    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    
        dependencies = [
            ("sites", "0015_populate_plans"),
        ]
    
        operations = [
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name="plan",
                name="recommended_for_text",
                field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=256, null=True),
            ),
        ]

0015_migration.py: (I think this must be what is failing but it works before adding the new column & 0016)
# Generated by Django 4.1.10 on 2024-04-03 14:02
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import migrations


def load_plans(apps, schema_editor):
    call_command('loaddata', 'plans.json', app_label='sites')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("sites", "0014_sitecommandlog_note"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_plans),
    ]

plans.json has a bunch of records like this (notably w/o the recommended_for_text field because it doesn't exist yet)
{
  "model": "sites.plan",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "portal_plan_name": "Basic",
    "plan_sku": "plan-basic_small-contract-annual-1",
    "traffic_limits": "35000",
    "annual_plan_charge": "224.00",
    "is_active": true
  }
}

Further strangeness I tried eliminating the actual tests from tests.py
This runs fine
from unittest import main
from django.test import TestCase


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

But this throws the no such column exception
from unittest import main
from django.test import TestCase

class SleepTest(TestCase):
    def test_sleep(self):
        from time import sleep
        sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


How are running tests? It looks like your DB migrations are not being applied to the test env

manage.py test app
It feels like it's trying to apply the 16th migration before the 15th though the dependencies all look correct to me and the app works fine, the tests have worked fine up until this 16th migration which just adds the nullable column.

Show your migrations that add the recommended_for_text field and the one you think is failing along with their names. (The migrations directory will have a python file for each of the migrations)

Added some more context, i edited the names a bit but i don't believe that is an issue here.

Can you just delete your testing dbs and rerun tests to see if the issue persists? -- this should rerun all migrations as needed...sometimes I have seen this issue in pytest when I close tests early

I was under the impression the test db goes away automatically and gets recreated every time?  It runs successfully when i roll back the migration or modify the tests to be empty.  I don't see a test database just sitting there but I didn't look too hard because I didn't expect it to exist.  The SleepTest was actually to look for it but that wont even run.

Your 0015_migration is very problematic. As a rule of thumb you shouldn't be calling the loaddata command from within a migration since it will use the current model rather than the historical model, this means that a migration might work when you just add it but might fail in the future when more changes are made to the model.
For now you can do the follows:
In 0015_migration replace load_plans in the arguments to RunPython with RunPython.noop:
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("sites", "0014_sitecommandlog_note"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]

Next if you really want to use the loaddata command do it externally from the migrations system. If you actually want to load data via migrations consider making data migrations that don't depend on the loaddata command. If you want to load fixtures with data migrations you can emulate what loaddata does by following the guidance in this question: Loading initial data with Django 1.7+ and data migrations
